# Repeat view in layout Android

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a question. I have a fragment in my app that displays the weather: title, temperature, condition, the icon, and some other stuff. What I'm trying to do is in the same fragment below all this information.

I want to display the forecast for the next 5 days, and each day will display the name of the day, condition, highest and lowest temperature and an icon. I want to display this forecast horizontally, each day next to the others.

But I don't want to repeat a bunch of TextViews and ImageViews for each day. Sort of like a ListView, but horizontally. Is there any way of do like a single view(with its textviews and imageview), and then repeat them for all the days in the forecast??

Thanks in advance, if you need some of my code, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, use a GridView (1 row, 5 columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

Use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and use the same layout multiple times using [`<include/>`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)